# Can't install xdebug on LAMPP with PHP 7.3.5

Tags: php, lamp, xampp, php7, xdebug

I've searched and read a lot of threads, and a lot of webs. Documentation of xdebug also.

But I continue developing without xdebug, and I really need it.

I followed installation instructions of few webs (for example: https://simplecodetips.wordpress.com/2018/07/12/instalar-xdebug-con-xampp-en-ubuntu-18-04/), but cannot complete it because I don't have a module called **enable-xdebug**.

Also I tried installing by PECL, and added **zend_extension="/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/xdebug.so"** and pointed the **php.ini** of XAMPP to the PATH indicate it after installation completes. This don't work.

When I load a page with phpinfo(), xdebug it's not in the result of any of the installations I do it.

I don't know what it's the problem, maybe the origin is XAMPP itself.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, after a lot more research, I found that maybe it's my problem: XAMPP 64 bit version.

From here I started to search for information about that issue and ended on the following page:
https://weekly-geekly.github.io/articles/91575/index.html

I followed those steps (watch out for the `--with-php-conig` flag in that post, it's mistyped and it is missing the 'f'. It should be `--with-php-config`). This finally got `Xdebug v2.8.0beta1` running on XAMPP 7.3.5 64 bits.

---

**EDIT: Added copied steps directly from the source**

## XAMPP on Linux + Xdebug (Linux 64bit)

So, today I managed to put XDebug on XAMPP for Linux. If you have a 32-bit Linux, you can not read the remaining text, you have a simple solution, and not one that can be easily found on the Web.

About the insane benefits of debugger for PCP do not even need to tell. On 64-bit whist / vindous7, the hdebag did not want to work at all (whist collapsed; there was no compiled version of the library for the seven)

For those who do not know: 
XAMPP - software package from apache + mysql + php + perl + proftpd + ... 
XDebug is a library for PHP. Allows you to clear scripts on PHP. (Mainly used together with IDE, for example Eclipse + PDT. Allows you to set breakpoints, debug step by step and watch the contents of variables)

If you come here from a search, then you are not interested in my adventures and searches, therefore, immediately to the point.

**Update:** Dear future readers, this article is for you if:

- You often need to switch between different web server configurations
  (for example PHP4 / 5.2 / 5.3) or for other reasons you are using
  XAMPP under Linux.
- You need XDebug
- You have 64-bit Linux
- By the time you start reading this post there is no 64bit HAMRP.

The rest, you can not read. I do not compare HAMRR with other existing solutions, I just have it, I use it with pleasure. I rummaged in the network and did not find a solution for my problem, so I decided to share with you here.

### System

Linux: Ubuntu 9.10 Karmic Koala 64bit 
XAMPP: v1.7.1 (with PHP 5.2.9) - I think for another version the process will be very similar.

### Installing XAMPP

Go here, choose the version you want. 
[sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files)

In my case, this is Linux XAMPP / 1.7.1.

We download files (for example, to the ~ / Downloads / xampp / directory):

**xampp-linux-devel - *. tar.gz**: contains the header files needed for compiling xdebug

**xampp-linux - *. tar.gz**: the XAMPP

### Install Ksamp and libraries in the / opt folder

```
# cd ~/Downloads/xampp

# sudo tar xzf xampp-linux-1.7.1.tar.gz -C /opt 

# sudo tar xzf xampp-linux-devel-1.7.1.tar.gz -C /opt
```

### Download xdebug

From here: xdebug.org/download.php 
we download the source code of the required version (I downloaded 2.1.0RC0 and 2.0.5). I downloaded in ~ / downloads / xdebug /

### Unpacking

```
# tar xzf xdebug* 

# cd xdebug*
```

### Installing other libraries

Honestly, I do not even know if they really are needed. But in order to compile FF for 32-bit from 64, it seems to be necessary

```
# sudo apt-get install ia32-libs gcc-multilib
```

### Configuring Environment Variables

For some reason, phpize flatly refused to work, complaining about **$ PHP_AUTOCONFIG** and **$ PHP_AUTOHEADER** without the following thing:

**Open with your editor:**

```
 ~/.bashrc
```

**In the end we add the line:**

```
export PATH=/opt/lampp/bin:$PATH
```

**Now in the shell:**

```
# export PATH=/opt/lampp/bin:$PATH 

# export PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR=/usr/lib/pkgconfig 

# export CC="gcc -m32" 

# export CXX="g++ -m32"
```

**We collect Xdebug for 32-bit**

```
# phpize 

# ./configure --enable-xdebug --with-php-config=/opt/lampp/bin/php-config --x-libraries=/usr/lib --target=i686-pc-linux 

# make
```

**We copy in a folder to Ksamp** *(Note from [me](https://askubuntu.com/users/965607/idontknoware): I don't know what is Ksamp, and why it's necessary here. Anyway, do this step, because it's basically the file who make work xDebug on your XAMPP.)*

```
# sudo cp modules/xdebug.so /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/
```

### Configuring PHP

```
# sudo gedit /opt/lampp/etc/php.ini
```

**Turn on the library (I added this on line 545)**

```
zend_extension="/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/xdebug.so"
```

**Start / restart and check**

```
# sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart 

# /opt/lampp/bin/php -i | grep xdebug 

xdebug 
xdebug support => enabled 
xdebug.auto_trace => Off => Off 
xdebug.collect_includes => On => On 
xdebug.collect_params => 0 => 0 
xdebug.collect_return => Off => Off 
xdebug.collect_vars => Off => Off 
xdebug.default_enable => On => On 
xdebug.dump.COOKIE => no value => no value 
xdebug.dump.ENV => no value => no value 
... 
..
```

Happy debugging!

PS: you can remove the added line from ~ / .bashrc

---

To see if you have xDebug enabled, go to your XAMPP dashboard, or create a .php file with that content in your **htdocs** path:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Load in your webbrowser -> CTRL+A -> CTRL+C -> [Go to xDebug wizard](https://xdebug.org/wizard.php) -> Paste it with in the textarea and click **Analyze my phpinfo() output** to see if you have enabled or not.

Comment: It is totally fine to answer your own questions. We [actually love that](https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer)! However, it could be much better if you can include some of the most important steps you followed from that article here in the answer. Links tend to become dead after a while, so important information for future users can be lost.

Comment: You are right. I'm gonna edit my answer with the steps I followed and some more explanation.

Comment: Work done. I hope this will help somebody like it did with me :)

Comment: I recompiled it as said in this tutorial but without -m32 parameters and is working now!